# ROS with Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,
I need your help. i want to install ROS in rasbian but i don't know how it works. i tried with some tutorials but it doesn't work.
Do you have experience to install ROS in raspbian image before?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228883/ros-with-raspberry-pi-3/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-03-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you have a Pi 2 Model B or newer then you can put Ubuntu 14.04 with ARM on it. Then it's as simple as using apt-get to download ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Trent](https://answers.ros.org/users/26251/trent/) with karma: 36 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-06**:
The rpi3 has a new broadcom chip in it and is ARMv8 whereas the rpi2b is ARMv7. Even if you install everything on an SD card on rpi2b and move the SD card over it won't matter. I tried that same scenario just this morning with no success..